# How to import and parse RSS feed from a WP site to a non-WP if 'allow_url_include' is set to 'off'?

Tags: rss, feed

I work in a secure environment where I am trying to import an RSS feed from a wordpress site to a non-wordpress site that resides on a remote server/domain. Unfortunately, this server has the 'allow_url_include' config set to "off" and therefore I can't pull in an RSS feed using a php include. What other options would I have in order to display RSS feeds on my non-WP site? Could I use a JSON API plugin in this case? I don't have to use RSS, but it's the only method I can think of in order to display the "latest 5 posts" onto my non-WP site.

Comment: This is not really a WordPress question? It's about making network request with PHP, better asked at [so].

Comment: I disagree. Could a WP plugin fulfill my needs in this case?

Comment: How does WP plugin help your remote non-WP site to make network request?

Comment: Rarst is correct, you need to ask this in a general PHP forum, not here. There's lots of ways to retrieve http documents with PHP code, and allow_url_fopen isn't the only way.

Comment: I actually had to update my question: It is the allow_url_include setting that is set to 'off', not the fopen.